# Img src not updated with publicPath using HtmlWebpackPlugin templateContent

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to generate a more ore less static html page using **HtmlWebpackPlugin** and **Handlebars**. Where everything works like a charm, using **templateContent** (function) instead of **template** (path) as an **option of HtmlWebpackPlugin**, img src is not updated in html when building.

Here is **index.html** (at: 'src/templates/index.html'):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{{ hello_world }}</h1>
  <img src="~assets/images/image.svg">
</body>
</html>
```

(I also tried "../../assets/images/image.svg" which has same results)

Here is **output index.html** (at: 'dist/index.html'):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/favicon.png"><link href="http://localhost/main.e0aba7a5294a4bfca93a1b95f4dc194a.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <img src="~assets/images/image.svg">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I am **expecting** the **output index.html** to have img src path updated like so:

```
<img src="http://localhost/img/image.svg">
```

Here is my (simplified) **webpack.config.js**:

```
  const path = require('path');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
  const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
  ...

  module.exports = {
    entry: ['./assets/styles/main.scss', './src/scripts/main.js'],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: 'http://localhost/',
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
      },
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        ...
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: ['html-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'img/',
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      ...
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        favicon: 'assets/images/favicon.png',
        templateContent: function(templateParams) {
          const templatePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/index.html');
          var source = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8');
          const context = require('./assets/data.json');
          return Handlebars.compile(source)(context);
        },
      })
    ]
  };
```

My **package.json** rughly looks like so:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "handlebars": "4.0.10",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.5",
  },
  ...
}
```

For now, I am replacing img src by hand in templateContent which kind of feels hacky.

(Note: Another issue I encountered is that hot reloading with webpack-dev-server won't work with this config. To fix this, I am actually also using template option in HtmlWebpackPlugin. Described problem remains same.)

Hope anyone has some ideas to get it working properly.
Thanks!

Comment: I noticed you are prefixing your assets folder with a tilde (~): `<img src="~assets/..." >`. Is the tilde a special convention used by Webpack, or did your intend `~/assets`, which would look in your home folder, or `./assets` which would look in the current folder? I say this because it appears that all other URLs in the template are being properly transformed.

Comment: Yes, this is webpack specific and not referring to the home folder. As I said "../../assets/images/image.svg" would also be a correct path, but as well not updated correctly.

Comment: Any suggestions? I guess the reason is that I am loading the template via "var source = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8');" which kind of bypasses webpack and causes image paths not to be replaced correctly. But: The images are exported correctly to dist folder.